# Counting With C# Using Linq Or NOT

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know this is a newbie question but anyway i apreciate any help ...

Supose i have a Dice

```
public class Dice
{
   public int FaceValue { get; set; }
   public Dice(int faceValue)
   {
      this.FaceValue = faceValue; 
   }
}
```

And a Result class ...

```
public class Result
{

   public Dice D1 { get; set; }
   public Dice D2 { get; set; }
   public Dice D3 { get; set; }

   // Always has three dices ...
   public Result(Dice d1,Dice d2,Dice d3)
   {
      D1 = d1;
      D2 = d2;
      D3 = d3; 
   }
}
```

And a class Bet ...

```
public class Bet
{
   // A bet could have one , two , or three dices ....
   public List<Dice> Dices = new List<Dice>();
}
```

Is there any very simple way (LINQ or not) to COUNT how many times a single Bet ( that can have one , two or three Dices )

appears in single Result that always have three dices ?

and if my List of Bets has more than one Bet , check if any Bet appears in a Result of three dices ?

For instance

```
Result.D1 = new Dice(1);
Result.D2 = new Dice(4);
Result.D3 = new Dice(1);

{ { new Dice(1), new Dice(4) } } appears 1 time ===> 1

{ { new Dice(1) } } appears 2 times ====> 2

{ { new Dice(4) , new Dice(1) , new Dice(1) } } appears 1 time ====> 1

{ { new Dice(5) , new Dice(2) , new Dice(3) } } doesn't appear ====> 0

{ { new Dice(1) , new Dice(6) , new Dice(6) },
{ new Dice(4) , new Dice(4) , new Dice(4) },
{ new Dice(1) , new Dice(2) , new Dice(3) },
{ new Dice(1) , new Dice(5) , new Dice(5) },
{ new Dice(1) , new Dice(1) , new Dice(4) },
{ new Dice(3) , new Dice(3) , new Dice(3) } } has one bet that is equal so ========> 1
```

Comment: Just FYI, the singular of "Dice" is "Die".

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the logic for your "bets". Is it just "pick some face value numbers, and if they show up you win those many times"?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Result
{

   public Dice D1 { get; set; }
   public Dice D2 { get; set; }
   public Dice D3 { get; set; }

   // Always has three dices ...
   public Result(Dice d1,Dice d2,Dice d3)
   {
      D1 = d1;
      D2 = d2;
      D3 = d3; 
   }

   public bool Match(IEnumerable<Dice> dice)
   {
        return ...; // Your comparison logic here
   }
}

var bets = new List<Bet>();

foreach(var bet in bets)
{
    var matchCount = bet.Count(x => Result.Match(x.Dices));
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code, give an explanation for how and why this works. The OP could have no idea the approach you are suggesting.

Comment: Artplastika you are almost there.How to compare a List<Dice> that could have 1 , 2 , or three with a result class that has three dice always.My problem is a simple way to count {1,2} is in {1,2,1} and this {1,1} is in {1,6,1} and {1,1} is not in { 1,4,5} could you understand ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var dice = ShortForm(new[]{result.D1, result.D2, result.D3});
var betGoodCount = bets.Count(bet => BetInDice(bet, dice));


Dictionary<int, int> ShortForm(IEnumerable<Dice> dice)
{
   return dice
      .GroupBy(die => die.FaceValue)
      .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count);
}
bool BetInDice(Bet bet, Dictionary<int, int> dice)
{
  return ShortForm(bet.Dice)
    .All(pair => dice.ContainsKey(pair.Key) && pair.Value <= dice[pair.Key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going under the assumption that you roll `x` number of dice and place `y` number of bets. You then want to compare if any or your bets was a number that was rolled.

First, you should change up how your `Bet` class is structured.

```
public class Bet
{
    public int FaceValue { get; set; }
}
```

The reason is that one `bet` relates to one `face value`. You will then have a list of bets, like this:

```
List<Bet> bets = new List<Bet>()
{
    new Bet() { FaceValue = 2 },
    new Bet() { FaceValue = 4 },
    //etc
};
```

Add these methods to your `Result` class:

```
private IEnumerable<int> CorrectBets(List<Dice> dice, List<Bet> bets)
{
    //use an linq join on their face values
    return from die in dice
           join bet in bets on die.FaceValue equals bet.FaceValue
           select die.FaceValue;
}

public int NumberOfCorrectBets(List<Bet> bets)
{
    var dice = new List<Dice>() { D1, D2, D3 };
    return CorrectBets(dice, bets).Count(); //this actually gets the count
}
```

The only thing you have to do now is create a `List<Bet>` object and pass that into the `NumberOfCorrectBets` method.

This should account for duplicate dice numbers / bet numbers. Meaning if you bet on a `3` and a `3` gets rolled 2 times, you will get 2 for an answer.

Comment: I will roll 3 dice ( btw thanks for the information ) resulting { 1 , 3, 5} and i have the followings bet { 1,1 } each number in this list represents a die. {1,1} is not in {1,3,5} but it is in { 1,4,1} i need to count how many times a bet appears in result .Icould have a bet of {1} that appears 3 times in a result { 1,1,1 } .Many thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user2757243, I'm very confused by what you mean. Can you edit your post to clear up the logic for checking if a bet is valid? Something like "If I bet `a, b, c` and I roll `d, e, f`, then I get `this` because `this reason`".